# How to make a timed traffic light sequence in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I am struggling on a project to make a timed traffic light sequence for my high school exams using JavaScript and I really don't know what I am doing. I have a rough plan and that includes styling the values inside my array (red, yellow and green) into lights using CSS.

I have been writing a code just to create the red light for practice and here is what I have:

```
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <script type = "JavaScript">
    var myLights = ["red", "Yellow", "green"]
    </script>
    <script type = "CSS">
    red {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 200px; 
    height: 200px; 
    color: #ff0000;
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Unsurprisingly, this has not worked as it hasn't come up with anything when I browse it in Google Chrome.

If anyone could give me some advice then that would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully no-one will do this homework for you, since it is very important to your learning process that you do it yourself. Nevertheless, readers here will generally understand that sometimes it is helpful to get some broad guidance.

Here is the order in which I would tackle this problem:

- Create three lights in static HTML and CSS. Here you'll probably want to use classes such as `light` (for all three lights) and then `red`, `amber` and `green` for the separate lights.
- To define them, use for example `.red {}` (not `red {}` as you have now).
- You can define common features of all lights using `.light {}` and then apply that to all lights.
- Each light will probably be a `<div>` and you'll need to apply one or more classes. For your first light, you could do something like `<div id="red_light" class="red light"></div>`.
- You may wish to have a fifth class of `on`, such that `red light` is off, and `red light on` is on. Perhaps you can use `opacity` here to control colours? There are several ways to do this.
- Once you are happy with your HTML and CSS, add some JavaScript. You'll need to consider how to move from one state to another, and planning this out on paper is helpful. Then write methods to add and remove classes from each of your divs.

One overall helpful piece of advice, and a technique I still sometimes use, is to write a bit of code and test it very frequently - even if one could write larger chunks of code before trying it. It is mentally helpful to see changes instantly, and reassures us as developers that we are on the right path.

Comment: Welcome, @Luke! Send me a JS Fiddle of your progress in the comments, if you like. Good luck!

Comment: And for the record, i have to use an array for some reason :(

Comment: Hmm @LukeP - maybe keeping the status of each light in an array could be done. But I'd just write a JS function to get the status of each light, either by index (0-2) or by colour. Maybe just do it your own way first, and then see how it could be modified?

Comment: Have you made any progress, based on my suggestions above?

Comment: Well i have decided that either changing the traffic light image when i click on a button. For example, i have 5 images of each traffic light state (British traffic light sequence) and every time i lick on a button it changes image. Alternatively i could make 3 div's and change between each of the 5 states (traffic light sequences) so every time i click, it switches.

Comment: This is my <div> method                                      file:///C:/Documents/Year%2010%20-%20Computer%20Science/A452%20contolled%20assessment/DIV%20based%20traffic%20light/flag_swap.html